# How do I rip CDs with Sound Juicer over X11 forwarding?

Tags: cd-drive, policykit

I am trying to rip a CD with Sound Juicer over X11 forwarding (CD is in the desktop across the room, I'm SSHing in from my laptop), but Sound Juicer cannot find my CD drive.  It works correctly when I am logged in directly to the machine in a GNOME session.  My user is in the `cdrom` group.

I suspect that some combination of udisks, PolicyKit, and ConsoleKit is to blame — that it is configured to allow users with active console sessions to enumerate and/or access drives, but not other users.

How can I configure my system to allow me to access this?  I cannot seem to locate any PolicyKit or ConsoleKit configuration programs like I seem to remember Fedora having when they rolled out PolicyKit?

The other option I see, which I find to be unlikely, is that Sound Juicer requires some GNOME session services to be running in order to locate the drive.

**Update**: Based on the accepted answer, it does require GNOME session services, namely a D-Bus session bus by which it can run gvfs.  If sound-juicer fails, running `dbus-launch sound-juicer` works.  Alternatively, `dbus-launch` can be hooked in to your login scripts to run at SSH login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the sound juicer source it requires both access to gconf and gvfs. It looks like it uses gvfs to see what cdrom drives you have available. Failure to access them or having gvfs policies which stop you seeing them will be a real problem.

I'd report this problem to the sound juicer bugs:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/describecomponents.cgi?product=sound-juicer

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to be the problem.  Running `sound-juicer` with `dbus-launch`, so it has a session bus and can thereby start gvfs, fixes it.